# Calculate bounding box based on given coordinates and distance/radius

Tags: php, math, coordinates, sparql, latitude-longitude

In a PHP script I have a SPARQL query returning POIs within a given distance of another point. This is the line in the query which handles the geo-filtering:

```
FILTER (?long > " . ($resource_long - $search_radius) . " && ?long <  " . ($resource_long + $search_radius) . " && ?lat >  " . ($resource_lat - $search_radius) . "  && ?lat <  " . ($resource_lat + $search_radius) . "  )
```

For now I have been using an integer (the variable $search_radius) to limit my results, and this would translate to degrees. There are, however, two problems with this. Firstly, using degrees as a parameter is not very user friendly, and kilometers would be to prefer. Secondly, the further away from the equator one gets, the narrower the distance gets between two degrees of longitude. This will in turn result in fewer returned results. So, the question is; given a lat/long coordinate, how can I calculate the bounding box based on a given radius/distance in km?

Answer (score 3):

Use radians for everything

then

```
   $radius = $distance/ 6371.01; //6371.01 is the earth radius in KM
   $minLat = $lat - $radius;
   $maxLat = $lat + $radius;
   $deltaLon = asin(sin($radius) / cos($lat));
   $minLon = $lon - $deltaLon;
   $maxLon = $lon + $deltaLon;
```

Then convert back to degrees if needed.

This doesnt work if bounds are crossed. There are classes available to help

https://github.com/anthonymartin/GeoLocation.php

For example

Thats the outer bounds, You can get the inner bounds square by doing multiplying by the $radius by cos(M_PI_4) for top lat, sin(M_PI_4) for top lon, cos(3*M_PI_4) for bottom lat and sin(3*M_PI_4) for bottom Lon

Comment: Does that end up giving a bounding box (or circle) of points equidistant from the starting point?  It still seems like it'd have the problem that the distance between the higher latitude points is smaller than the distance between the lower latitude points.  My trig is rusty though, so I may be missing something.

Comment: Gives a bounding box ( or 2 if the bottom one is used also). As it is handles the vast majority of points

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not getting the results expected. I set up a test environment with map and grid, and a function to draw lines between the points, so that it gives me a visual representation of the box I'm creating. At 0 degrees lat/long it gives me a nice square. My original concern was that it would be a rectangle which is higher and higher, compared to it's width, the further away from equator I get. The results I'm seeing now, however, is rectangles of all shapes. At some point I also get a NAN-value (not-a-number?) from PHP.

Comment: I don't remember/understand much of the math, so it's kinda hard for me to debug this. Do you have any references that might help me understand it? You may also have a test with my map prototype: [link](http://sunhill.ddns.net/geo/radians.php?lat=0&lon=0&distance=5000) Just play around with the parameters and it will draw the box and put a marker on the center.

Comment: Are you using that libary ?

Comment: Code I posted doesn't handle extremes. He when you cross a boundary. But its easier to implement for a test

Comment: How to define the value of $distance based on the z value of xyz tile?